# Getting the length of a BiSet instance

Tags: java, bitset

I have a function which takes as argument a BiSet object. I have the following

```
public static void(String [] args)
{
   BitSet test = new BitSet(15);

     Store(test);
}

public void Store (BitSet a)
{
  boolean [] temp = new boolean[a.length()]();
  System.out.println(temp.length);
}
```

The problem is that the length of my temp or a is 64. How can I get the actual length (15) of the object instance test that I passed to the function Store?

Comment: Your `BitSet` probably does not have a length of 15 bits. [`new BitSet(15)`](//docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#BitSet-int-) ensures that it can hold 15 bits.

Comment: What is “actual length” and how is it different from length?  A BitSet does not have a distinct size;  it can only report the highest bit which is set.

Comment: yes but but when I have temp.length, I have 64 and not 15. I could have set the 10th bits but still want temp to have a length of 15 bits (I could set the others later)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The [constructor documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#BitSet(int)) says:

> Creates a bit set whose initial size is large enough to explicitly represent bits with indices in the range `0` through `nbits-1`.

There's no guarantee that the initial size won't be *larger* than the requested size. In fact, `nbits` is lost by the time the constructor completes.

But there's really no reason you should need the initial size in real code.

Comment: If that is not possible, is there any other data structure that I can use and on which I can apply (Set, OR, AND, XOR) efficiently (I am thinking about something like BitArray in C#)

Comment: @user3841581 you can use a simple `int` or `long`. But you won't get exactly 15 bits. It's still not clear why you would even want that.

Comment: The issue is not getting 15 bits, it is having a Boolean array on which I can efficiently perform the operations I mentioned earlier in an efficient way

Comment: @user3841581 Then `BitSet` should do just fine.

Comment: But I would like to keep a specific size, as I have some loops that are based on the length of the BitSet. That is my issue

Comment: @user3841581 so create a variable `int size = 15;`